# Enable external users to un-silence my phone

Tags: silent-mode, do-not-disturb

I have my phone on do-not-disturb or silent virtually always. I usually see my phone, and can see I'm being called.

However, sometimes my SO needs to reach me quickly, and I just happen to not see my phone. I want her to somehow be able to force my phone to ring then.

I seem to recall someone talking about being able to do this on their phone: if their SO called them 3 times in rapid succession, the phone would enable sound. I don't remember what phone or app or such this was using.

I want something similar. It doesn't have to be the exact same thing, but I simply want my SO to have a way to quickly, without much effort, be able to reach me even when my phone is on do-not-disturb. (the advantage of the 3-call thing is that you can do it while driving using the on-board hands-free system, no additional effort needed).

Can anyone point me to how to do this?

Some additional info: My SO uses an iPhone, I have a Nokia 6.1 running android 9

Comment: You can add the SO to the priority list in do not disturb. Or you can use an app like tasker to change ringer based on their number.

Comment: Just for curiosity what is a "SO"?